# How to deploy a LightSwitch html application to localhost from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: lightswitch-2013

What's the user name,password and service URL on light switch. When i give service URL to localhost it shows error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only specify localhost as the service URL, you'll see the following error when validating the connection (though it may go on to still publish successfully):

[image: localhost publish validation error]

However, if you instead specify http://localhost, you should see the following successful confirmation message:

[image: localhost publish success error]

If this isn't the error you're experiencing, you could try running Visual Studio as Administrator to see if it makes a difference to the process of publishing.

In addition, the following IIS settings (based on IIS 10) may need to be configured alongside the default options: -

**Additional "Turn Windows feature on or off" settings**

.NET Framework 4.6 Advanced Services \ WCF Services

- HTTP Activation
- TCP Port Sharing

Internet Information Services \ Web Management Tools

- IIS Management Console
- IIS Management Service

Internet Information Services \ World Wide Web Services \ Application Development Features

- .NET Extensibility 3.5
- .NET Extensibility 4.6
- ASP.NET 3.5
- ASP.NET 4.6
- ISAPI Extensions
- ISAPI Filters

Internet Information Services \ World Wide Web Services \ Health and Diagnostics

- HTTP Logging
- Logging Tools
- Request Monitor

Internet Information Services \ World Wide Web Services \ Security

- Request Filtering
- Windows Authentication

**Options in IIS**

- Default Web Site Home \ IIS Group \ Authentication \ Enable Forms Authentication
- Main Server Node \ RHS Actions \ Get New Web Platform Components \ Installed Web Deployment Tool 2.1

The following blog posts, by the LightSwitch team, contain additional details regarding the publish process which may help and is still fairly relevant despite relating to earlier versions of LightSwitch:

[LightSwitch IIS Deployment Enhancements in Visual Studio 2012](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2012/03/29/lightswitch-iis-deployment-enhancements-in-visual-studio-2012/)

[Deployment Guide: How to Configure a Web Server to Host LightSwitch Applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2011/03/23/deployment-guide-how-to-configure-a-web-server-to-host-lightswitch-applications/)